# How to configure Tomcat to not encode the session id into the URL when HttpServletResponse.encodeURL() is invoked

Tags: java, tomcat, url-rewriting, session

Seems like a stupid question to which the answer would be "Don't use encodeURL()!" but I'm working with a codebase that uses netui anchor tags in the JSPs and I need to disable the writing of JSESSIONID into the URLs as it is a security risk.

In WebLogic, you can configure this by configuring url-rewriting-enabled in weblogic.xml (I know because I wrote that feature in the WebLogic server!). However, I can't find an equivalent config option for Tomcat.

Comment: If you consider having the session ID on the URL as a security risk, then how is relying on the same information in a cookie any less of a risk?

Comment: One could (unawarely/accidently) copypaste an URL with `jsessionid` from address bar and give it to someone else. The other -either unawarely or awarely and with bad intents- could request the page with this URL as if it was the original user. With cookies, the `jsessionid` is not directly visible to the enduser. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation

Comment: That doesn't sound like security, that's more of a safety issue. If security against exploits is the concern, then a cookie is no more secure than a rewritten URL, surely.

Comment: Yes, it's more a safety issue. The responsibility for security and leaks is also entirely on the client side, not on the server side.

Comment: Another concern with session IDs in the URL are referrer URLs. If you click on a link to an external site, the old URL is sent to the new HTTP server in the Referer field, enabling a malicious target site to take over the session. Add bot-generated comment posts and your users are in danger.

Comment: @skaffman: Cookies can be protected against client-side attacks like CSRF and XSS. The page URL cannot be protected. This is a necessary step (along with using the secure and http-only flags on the cookie) to reduce the risk of session hijacking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No setting comes to mind. But this is fairly easy to do by creating a first-entry `Filter` listening on the `url-pattern` of interest (maybe `/*` ?) and replaces the `ServletResponse` by a [`HttpServletResponseWrapper`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) implementation where the `encodeURL()` returns the very same argument unmodified back.

Kickoff example:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    chain.doFilter(request, new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response) {
        public String encodeURL(String url) {
            return url;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it... remember, though, there are 4 different url-rewriting methods on the response, some or all of which might need "disabling".

Comment: Correct. 2 of them are however deprecated (ending in `Url` instead of `URL`). The other one which you may want to override as well is the `encodeRedirectURL()`. Also see http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeRedirectURL%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I did for Tomcat and I can confirm that it works.

Answer (score 9):

Tomcat 6 supports the `disableURLRewriting` attribute that can be set to `true` in your Context element:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes

Comment: Another property to consider is httpOnly, which prevents client-side scripts from accessing the session ID.

Comment: If you are using http and not https and have set secure="true" on the tomcat Connector, then setting disableURLRewriting to true will not work.

Answer (score 0):

As found in https://fralef.me/tomcat-disable-jsessionid-in-url.html - There is a servlet spec feature to do this

```
<session-config>
   <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```